# Android Studio getIntent from one activity but not from other

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a question that whatever I search i can't find the answer for.
So I have 3 Activities:StartActivity, LoginActivity and MainActivity
In StartActivity I have 2 buttons:
-Login - it sends me to LoginActivity
-Continue as guest - it sends me to MainActivity
In Login activity i have:

```
 login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    if(loginUser(false)) {
                        String username = String.valueOf(userName);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("USERNAME", username);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

and in MainActivity I have :

```
private String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME");
```

But when I try to login as guest the String username has nothing to get and gives me error. So how can I make String username getIntent only when I open the activity from LoginActivity and don't do anything when I open it from ContinueAsGuest button in StartActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

button in StartActivity only take you as guest right?if so code will look like this

```
guestBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    
                        String username = String.valueOf(userName);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("USERNAME", username);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            
        });
```

Comment: It StartActivity I have only 2 buttons - login and continue as guest.
 String username = String.valueOf(userName); doesn't have anything to take from there.
I want when i open MainActivity to getIntent if i was in LoginActivity or don't getIntent if i loged from StartActivity

Comment: you can use null check .If(getIntent!=null && getIntent.getStringExtrar!=null){ "here get value"}